How to draw a line with rounded edge in D3?
I got at task that requires an X & check mark in D3.

I tried to add an svg to the existing chart, but it does scale well since the svg keeps its dimension.
So, I tried it another way to directly draw two lines in the chart at the desired position. However, the line doesn't have round edge.

Any idea on how to create them in D3? Thanks,

Use .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round'), see here.  Example here.
